# How to deal with the North tribe action defecit?

Tags: as-far-as-the-eye

In "As far as the Eye", pupils from the North tribe consume labour to stay alive indirectly in three different ways.

1. 6 units of food are needed per turn per pupil.*
2. 2 units of wool are needed per turn per pupil.*
3. 1 health is needed per turn per pupil. This is 5% of a potion, or 20% of one turn of personal attention from the healer. The healer themselves can only use a potion.

*If either food or wool is unavailable, an additional 20 health is lost each turn.

When starting out, Food is typically harvested at a rate of 10 per turn per pupil (40 per harvest, 3 turns of harvesting, at least 1 turn of walking). Same for Wool. This means the starting setup, not considering potions is 80% subsistent.

Potions are very inefficient. It takes 20 units of pepkins, 20 units of spices, 8 units of wood, 3 turns of labour, and 4 or so turns of moving pupils to make a single potion that only heals 20 health. Combined it is about 12 turns of labour or so, broken down like:

```
    2 turns pepkin harvests 
    2 turns spice harvests 
    1 turn wood
    3 turns making a potion
    2 turns walking to places
    1 turn healing the patient
    1 turn having the patient walk to the heal location.
```

So in the end, concocting potions for everyone would be about 140% subsistent (meaning, it takes 14 pupils to keep 10 pupils alive). Even for just one out of the three you're at 100%, so have no more 'healer attention time'. Nor time to build buildings, or collect resources for getting to the next halt.

The game hitting you right off the bat with its full intensity means there's a massive difficulty hump in the first few halts. I find that most of the time, the pupils die from either Starvation (either Food or Wool slowly runs out), or losing all their health to Puny shortly after making it to the second halt. I suspect that the game might become much easier if this intitial difficulty is dealt with as it tends to scale its difficulty poorly.

Playing North tribe feels like being stuck in a debt trap, with no way to get out. The tribe is running at a big defecit, and you have very little time to turn this defecit around; as the starting food and wool stocks only last for 70 or so turns.

**How can one effectively increase the productivity within those turns?** Or, am I forced to re-roll the tribe until one of the 'broken' traits appears such as *Abstemious* or *Agile*? I'm looking for build orders that don't wither and die most of the time.

---

One way of making the overhead smaller is to recruit more pupils, so your existing ones can only do one task. For example: Adding two more pupils means Wool-gathering becomes a full-time job. This tends to run into problems on the second halt: The number of pepkins on the map often won't sustain the whole tribe anymore, and Cooking is needed (pepkins are the only food that can be consumed raw). Cooking is ineffective for North tribe: There's twice the normal Wood used, meaning you need 1.8 pupils to generate 20 food per turn; not exactly any better than gathering, you don't start with any experience, Cookhouse and Bakery are expensive buildings, and the way Cooking is done tends to play poorly with micromanaging the Healer to heal workers versus just gathering: The cook has less movement options while staying efficient.